# R stepwise regression model iteration by column name (data table)

Tags: r, data.table, regression

I have a `.csv` file and input in R used `fread()` function from library`data.table`.

The file which input in R with `8928 obs` and `71 variable`.

Here is data content with 71 columns and 8928 rows called `DT` :

```
01F0017S 01F0029S 01F0061S ... 01F3676S 01F3686S 01F3736S
49.25    47.58    119.00       116.77   34.00    188.44
....
52.25    49.40    199.18   ... 118.83   33.10    186.13
```

Then I created two `data.table` called `TrainDT` and `PracticeDT` by:

```
TrainDT<-DT[1:round(0.7*nrow(DT),0)]
PracticeDT<-DT[round(0.7*nrow(DT),0):nrow(DT)]
```

I wrote a for loop to  fit stepwise regression model `step()` and `predict()` it.

Fit model as follow step:

Step 1:

I shift the `TrainDT` to a `TrainModel` data.table with `2673 obs`, `72 variables` and `cbind()` a new column called `01F0017S_y`

```
TrainModel<-cbind(setnames(TrainDT[7:nrow(TrainDT),i,with=F],paste0(names(DT[1,i,with=FALSE]),'_y')),TrainDT[1:(nrow(TrainDT)-6),1:length(TrainDT),with=F])
```

The content of `TrainModel`:

```
01F0017S_y  01F0017S 01F0029S 01F0061S ... 01F3676S 01F3686S 01F3736S
43.74       49.25    47.58    119.00       116.77   34.00    188.44
....
44.55       52.25    49.40    199.18   ... 118.83   33.10    186.13
```

Step 2:

Here is my problem:

I use `lm` to fit a regression model and `step(lm,direction='both')` script as follow:

```
Fitmodel<-lm(`01F0017S_y`~.,data=TrainModel)
stepwise<-step(Fitmodel,sacle=0,direction = 'both')
```

How can I make this linear model to fit stepwise regression in different name with column `_y`?

For instance:

```
Fitmodel<-lm(`01F0017S_y`~.,data=TrainModel)
Fitmodel<-lm(`01F0029S_y`~.,data=TrainModel)
Fitmodel<-lm(`01F0061S_y`~.,data=TrainModel)
```

The loop I write will create those variable with `_y` automatically but dont know how to assign to iteration.

I try some way to assign the variable `_y` but always fail because the model will put variable `_y` with the respond variable.

ex. `Fitmodel<-lm(TrainModel[[1]]~.,data=TrainModel)`

The `_y` will put with others variable as follow pic:

[image]

And I try this way:

```
x<-paste(names(DT[1,1,with=FALSE]),'_y',sep ='' )
ModelTest_8<-lm(`x`~.,data=TrainModel)
```

With error information:

[image]

How to iteration a stepwise regression with different `_y` variable?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of reproducible data, here's an solution using iris data:

```
dat <- iris[, !names(iris) %in% "Species"]    
responses<- grep("Length", names(iris), value=T)
predictor <- grep("Width", names(iris), value=T)
models <- lapply(responses, function(x) as.formula(paste(x, paste(predictor,collapse="+"), sep="~")))

models
[[1]]
Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width
<environment: 0x0000000015c28de0>

[[2]]
Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width
<environment: 0x0000000015c2c9e0>


fits <- lapply(models, lm, data=dat)
steps <- lapply(fits, step, sacle=0, direction="both")
```